# Flow type erroneously thinks I'm passing props to a component in a render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Consider the following:

```
render(): ?React.Element<*> {
  if (this.state.error) {
    if (redirect) return <Redirect to={redirect} />;
    return <Page404 />;
  }
  ...
}
```

Flow is giving me the error:

> property 'to'
>   Property not found in props of React element 'Page404'

Why does flow think I'm passing `Page404` a `to` prop? How can I correct this?

Comment: @AndrewLi, yep, just finished updating

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning `?React.Element<*>`, Flow has to replace the `*` with some type parameters that satisfies all possible return values. In this case, one of those type parameters is `Props` -- so it has to find a type it can put there that matches both `Page404` and `Redirect`. Since they do not have matching `Prop`s, Flow cannot do this.

The simple solution is to change the return type to `?React.Element<any>`. Since callers rarely care about what specific element they have, and actually just want any React element, you are not losing any safety by using `any` in this case.